# Sharing Android Studio project to Github without giving access to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, github, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a personal project, which is on github, but is now private, because it uses firebase database, and using the app lets you control my house lights, etc.

**How can I make my app public without letting using my database?**

App doesn't require any authentication.

Comment: Add the files to gitIgnore and dont push them in GITHUB. Or you can also replace the credentials.

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee I'm a begginer and don't really know which files store the credentials because I used the assistant to set my DB up. Is it .json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't check in your google-services.json file. This is where the app gains knowledge of how to access the database.  Instruct the users of your source code to create their own Firebase project and add their own google-services.json file to the project to get their own database to work with.

By the way, if your app doesn't use Firebase Authentication and it's given permission to read and write the database, then anyone who knows the name of your project will also be able to read and write the database.  The name of your database can be gained by simply breaking down the APK.

Comment: Ahh, so there's no way I could share my code without using authentication. got it!